# EF CORE multiple properties that map to the same table

Tags: c#, .net, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this data model that I cant make it work.
One `User` can be associated to a `Company` **AND** multiple at the same time.
However a `Company` has multiple `Users`
Image example below:
[image]
I have tried to set relations on the modelBuilder like this:

```
 builder
        .HasMany(c => c.Users)
        .WithOne(u => u.CurrentAssociatedCompany)            
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.CurrentAssociatedCompanyId)
        .IsRequired();
```

But i get an error in the migration

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')

Even researched about InverseProperty but no luck there either.
**My question, is it possible to achieve this or should I try a different approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the relationship between `User` and `Company`, you could design the model as shown:

*Model*

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int CurrentAssociatedCompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company CurrentAssociatedCompany { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserCompany> UserCompanies { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserCompany> UserCompanies { get; set; }
}
public class UserCompany
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

*DbContext*

```cs
public class MVCDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MVCDbContext(DbContextOptions<MVCDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCompany>()
            .HasKey(uc => new { uc.UserId,uc.CompanyId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCompany>()
            .HasOne(uc=>uc.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.UserCompanies)
            .HasForeignKey(uc=>uc.CompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCompany>()
                .HasOne(uc => uc.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.UserCompanies)
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```cs
public IActionResult GetUserData(int? id)
{
    var userData = _context.User
                .Include(u => u.CurrentAssociatedCompany)
                .Include(u => u.UserCompanies)
                    .ThenInclude(uc => uc.Company)
                .Where(u=>u.Id==id)
                .Select(u => new
                {
                    UserId = u.Id,
                    UserName = u.UserName,
                    Age = u.Age,
                    CurrentAssociatedCompany = u.CurrentAssociatedCompany.CompanyName,
                    AssociatedCompanies = u.UserCompanies.Select(uc => new {
                        Id=uc.Company.Id,
                        CompanyName=uc.Company.CompanyName
                    }).ToList()
                });

    return Json(userData);
}
```

*Result*
[image: GIF of result]

For many-to-many relationship in EF Core, you could refer to [the official doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Comment: WOW! Thank you for such a detailed answer, I'm so grateful for that!  
I see your logic, basically just add a many-to-many relation with a join table.  
Thank you once again :)

Comment: how did you insert data to the table in this case, i followed this and got error while i was adding the data   PostgresException: 23502: null value in column "CompanyId" of relation "AspNetUsers" violates not-null constraint